# $state.go send params to conroller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

в контроллере

```
if (response.user.state == 'active') {
    $scope.isNewUser = 0;
    console.log('response.user.email ');
    console.log(response.user.email);
    $state.go('login.login' , {'prefillEmail': response.user.email});
    //
}
```

app.js

```
.state('login.login', {
    url: '/login',
    params: { redirect: { value: '' } },
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl',
    resolve: {
        redirect: function($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.redirect;
        }
    }
})
```

контроллер login.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, authService, redirect, $state, $location, $stateParams) {

        $scope.credentials = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };

        console.log('$stateParams');
        console.log($stateParams);

        console.log('$state');
        console.log($state);



        $scope.authenticate = function() {

            authService.login($scope.credentials)
            .then(function(response) {

                //Redirecting to hostname. Route check user type and return needed URL
                $location.path(redirect || '/');
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Вопрос в том как мне получить значение `prefillEmail` в login controller? Через `$stateParams` ничего не приходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы параметр стал доступен нужно его инициализировать через app.js
 просто задав ему null.

```
.state('login.login', {
        url: '/login',
        params: {
            redirect: { value: '' },
            prefillEmail: null
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        resolve: {
            redirect: function($stateParams) {
                return $stateParams.redirect;
            }
        }
    })
```

Ответ нашел сдесь https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/928